# Matlab Output different for same kind of code

Tags: arrays, matlab

i have to loops in matlab do similar kind of calculation but give different end values.
In first code i have gaven array ''theta'' with initial values and following code works as

```
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        sum=sum + (theta'*X(j,:)' - y(j))*X(j,i);
    end
    theta(i)=(theta(i)-(alpha*sum)/m);
    sum=0;
end
```

> the output of above code is 340403.617738 , 109912.678489 , -5931.109115

In second code i have gaven array ''theta'' with initial values but i have initializes ''theta_b'' equal to ''theta'' another array and all the changes i made is to array ''theta_b'' and at end i assigned valus of ''theta_b'' to ''theta''.

```
theta_b=theta;
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        sum=sum + (theta'*X(j,:)' - y(j))*X(j,i);
    end
    theta_b(i)=(theta(i)-(alpha*sum)/m);
    sum=0;
end
theta=theta_b;
```

> the output of above code are 340403.617738 , 110014.524234 , -6046.767912

since both above code shouls works as same so why output is different.
Since

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name, how would you then sum the values in `theta`? `sum(theta)` wil be baaad. Also: in your second case you keep using the old value of `theta` in the loop. In the first case, you're gradually changing the elements of `theta`, which you reuse in later iterations. That's why the first output is the same in both codes.

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop, you are updating the values of theta(i) and using the updated values in computing the sum. In the second loop, you are making a copy of theta at the beginning and using it throughout for your computing the sum. The new changes are saved instead into theta_b(i), which is not used in computing the sum.